# Iframe autoResize height with comment social plugin getting cut off as of today

Tags: facebook, height, autoresize, fluid

As of today my social commenting plugin is getting cut off.

In my tab page settings I chose fluid for height.

I have my main div with height:100%

Then i have a script that I used to auto resize the page and show all the comments if you clicked show more. This was working fine yesterday.

```
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
    }  
    </script>
```

Here is a link to my tab page:
http://hostfb.com/files/2598/af1d87a797314ed16ec3db8b3f094c45f30f8cf3/
https://www.facebook.com/dewafelbakkers?sk=app_246342282051389

I need my page to extend to show ten comments and then extend more to show more comments if clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the fixed height of 500 on the div that wraps the plugin control (right about fb-root div).

Comment: Thank you for your help this worked perfectly.Sometimes its so obivious you miss it!!